# Fetching specific value from a variable in Bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have a variable which runs a specific bash command:

```
Model=`some bash commad`
```

The output of `echo $Model` can be as below:

```
Model            = Model RZ230
```

I want to grab only the value `Model RZ230`

I am using the following but it is not working:

```
Model=`some bash commad | awk '{print $2}'
```

Using above command I am getting output as:

```
RZ230
```

`My output should be

```
Model RZ230
```

Comment: Add `-F=` to your `awk` command so that it uses `=` as a field separator and consider the 2nd field you're already printing as what follows the `=`

Comment: how should `awk` look like in such a case?

Comment: `awk -F= '{print $2}'`, but I recommend you go with Matias' answer, parameter expansion features are useful to know and much more performant that having to launch an executable

Comment: Also, if you launch an executable it might as well be `cut` for such a simple use-case, it's specialized in cutting lines into fields and returning only some of these. `cut -d= -f2` would be the equivalent to the previously mentionned `awk` command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Bash parameter expansion :

```
var="Model            = Model RZ230"
echo "${var##*= }"
Model RZ230
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering Perl, below would work

```
$ export data="Model            = Model RZ230"

$ perl -ne ' s/(.*)=\s*(.*)/\2/g; print ' <<< $data
Model RZ230

$ perl -e '$x=$ENV{data}; $x=~s/(.*)=\s*(.*)/\2/g; print "$x\n" '
Model RZ230

$
```